# Use one function for the "ComboboxSelected", to read multiple combobox

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use the same selection event for multiple combobox; is it possible? I can't find a way to pass to the function, the sender of the event.

```
    def newselection(self, event, {????}):
        self.selection = self.{????}.get()
        print(self.selection)

    self.combo1 = Combobox(self, width=7)
    self.combo1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.newselection({????}))
    self.combo1['values'] = ('a', 'c', 'g', 't')
    self.combo1.place(x=250, y=400)
    self.combo1.state(['readonly'])

    self.combo2 = Combobox(self, width=7)
    self.combo2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.newselection({????}))
    self.combo2['values'] = ('X', 'Y', 'XX', 'XY')
    self.combo2.place(x=450, y=400)
    self.combo2.state(['readonly'])
```

So it doesn't matter what combo is selected, I can use the same function and read the sender so I can allocate the value of the combobox correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bind` expects function name - it means without `()` and arguments. But it executes this functionw with `event` which gives access to widget - `event.widget`

Working example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# --- functions ---

def newselection(event):
    print('selected:', event.widget.get())

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

cb1 = ttk.Combobox(root, values=('a', 'c', 'g', 't'))
cb1.pack()
cb1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", newselection)

cb2 = ttk.Combobox(root, values=('X', 'Y', 'XX', 'XY'))
cb2.pack()
cb2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", newselection)

root.mainloop()
```

If you need more arguments then you have to use `lambda`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# --- functions ---

def newselection(event, other):
    print('selected:', event.widget.get())
    print('other:', other)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

cb1 = ttk.Combobox(root, values=('a', 'c', 'g', 't'))
cb1.pack()
cb1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event:newselection(event, "Hello"))

cb2 = ttk.Combobox(root, values=('X', 'Y', 'XX', 'XY'))
cb2.pack()
cb2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event:newselection(event, "World"))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! Works perfectly. BTW how do I get the sender name? I did try to print 'event.widget' but I get the object, not the name itself.

Comment: do you meen name of variable ? why do you need this name ? with 'event.widget' you have access to all properties of this widget.

Comment: BTW: you can also create new properties in widget ie. `cb1.my_name = "James Bond"` and then you can use it in function `print(event.widget.my_name)`

Comment: Right; I didn't realize that I can access everything, since the IDE was not giving me the properties while typing :)